# Apache Mina x Poodle bug

Tags: mina, poodle-attack

How do I disable ssl v3 support in apache mina SslFilter?
https://mina.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply specify only the protocols supported (in this case, all protocols from the `TLS` family. Code:

```java
final SslFilter sslFilter = new SslFilter(sslContext);
sslFilter.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1"});
acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("ssl", sslFilter);
```